# File exists in my Visual Studio 2010 solution but not deployed to Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have a sitemap.xml.gz file in my solution, and when I run the app locally, the file is available at http://localhost:123/sitemap.xml.gz.

However, when I deploy to Azure, the same path (but with my real domain) gives a 404. It's as if the file isn't there.

VS automatically set the `Build Action` for the file to `none`, but should it be a different value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the Build Action to Content. This will usually ensure it is copied.